# Modifying JSON reads and writes in playframework 2.1

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.1

I'm a newbie and scala/play and need help with playframework's JSON reads/writes.

I use Json.reads[T] and Json.writes[T] macros to define json reads and writes for my classes. However I'd like to have one property name to be (always) mapped differently. Namely, I have property named `id` in my classes and I want it to be represented as `_id` when object is converted to json and vice versa.

Is there a way to modify reads/writes objects generated by Json.reads and Json.writes macros to achieve this or do I have to rewrite reads and writes manually just to have one property named differently?

**EDIT**

Let me try to explain the problem better. Consider the model object User:

```
case class User (id: BigInt, email: String, name: String)
```

When serializing User to json for purposes of serving json in context of a REST api the json should look like this:

{
  "id": 23432,
  "name": "Joe",
  "email: "joe@example.com"
}

When serializing User to json for purposes of storing/updating/reading form MongoDB json should look like:

{
  "_id": 23432,
  "name": "Joe",
  "email: "joe@example.com"
}

In other words everything is the same except when communicating with Mongo `id` should be represented as `_id`.

I know I could manually write two sets of reads and writes for each model object (one to be used for web and another for communication with Mongo) as suggested by Darcy Qiu in the answer, however maintaining two sets of reads and writes that are nearly identical except for the id property seems like a lot of code duplication so I'm wondering if there is a better approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say your case class, which is `T` in your question, is named `User` and has definision as below

```
case class User(_id: String, age: Int)
```

Your reads can be defined as

```
implicit val userReads = new Reads[User] {
  def reads(js: JsValue): User = {
    User(
      (js \ "id").as[String],
      (js \ "age").as[Int]
    )
  }
}
```

Your `writes[User]` should follow the same logic.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Take a look at the updated question, I was hoping to avoid manually writing reads/writes two times when only difference is in how the id property is serialized.

Comment: I see. The best approach I can think of is to have two different `Format`s to cope with the two scenarios respectively.

Comment: I ended up with 2 sets of reads and writes as suggested in the answer so I'm going to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

First you define transformations for renames id/_id back and forth:

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.modules.reactivemongo.json._

val into: Reads[JsObject] = __.json.update( // copies the full JSON
  (__ \ 'id).json.copyFrom( (__ \ '_id).json.pick ) // adds id
) andThen (__ \ '_id).json.prune  // and after removes _id

val from: Reads[JsObject] = __.json.update( // copies the full JSON
  (__ \ '_id).json.copyFrom( (__ \ 'id).json.pick ) // adds _id
) andThen (__ \ 'id).json.prune  // and after removes id
```

(To understand why `Reads` is a transformation please read: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaJsonTransformers)

Assuming we have macro generated `Writes` and `Reads` for our entity class:

```
def entityReads: Reads[T] // eg Json.reads[Person]
def entityWrites: Writes[T] // eg Json.writes[Person]
```

Then we mix transformations with macro-generated code:

```
private[this] def readsWithMongoId: Reads[T] = 
  into.andThen(entityReads)
private[this] def writesWithMongoId: Writes[T] =
  entityWrites.transform(jsValue => jsValue.transform(from).get)
```

The last thing. Mongo driver wants to be sure (ie typesafe-sure) that the json it inserts is a JsObject. That is why we need an `OWrites`. I haven't found better way than:

```
private[this] def oWritesWithMongoId = new OWrites[T] {
  override def writes(o: T): JsObject = writesWithMongoId.writes(o) match {
    case obj: JsObject => obj
    case notObj: JsValue => 
      throw new InternalError("MongoRepo has to be" +
      "definded for entities which serialize to JsObject")
  }
```

}

Last step is to privide an implicit `OFormat`.

```
implicit val routeFormat: OFormat[T] = OFormat(
  readsWithMongoId,
  oWritesWithMongoId
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put in enough code you can achieve this with transformers:

```
val idToUnderscore = (JsPath).json.update((JsPath).read[JsObject].map { o:JsObject =>
  o ++ o.transform((JsPath\"_id").json.put((JsPath\"id").asSingleJson(o))).get
}) andThen (JsPath\"id").json.prune
val underscoreWrite = normalWrites.transform( jsVal => jsVal.transform(idToUnderscore).get )
```

Here's the full test:

```
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
import play.api.libs.json._

val u = User("overlord", "Hansi Meier", "evil.overlord@hansi-meier.de")

val userToProperties = {u:User => (u.id, u.name, u.email)}
val normalWrites = (
   (JsPath\"id").write[String] and
   (JsPath\"name").write[String] and
   (JsPath\"email").write[String]
 )(userToProperties)

val idToUnderscore = (JsPath).json.update((JsPath).read[JsObject].map { o:JsObject =>
  o ++ o.transform((JsPath\"_id").json.put((JsPath\"id").asSingleJson(o))).get
}) andThen (JsPath\"id").json.prune
val underscoreWrite = normalWrites.transform( jsVal => jsVal.transform(idToUnderscore).get )

info(Json.stringify(Json.toJson(u)(normalWrites)))
info(Json.stringify(Json.toJson(u)(underscoreWrite)))
```

Now, if you modify the normalWrites (say by adding additional properties), the underscoreWrite will still do what you want.

Comment: I wrote a test to assert that this works.
It still feels like there should be a better way to transform the Writes. I'd appreciate any suggestions how to improve the code.